# "---please make a choise---" prestashop form

Tags: prestashop

i would like to make default "---please make a choice--'. Actually in checkout adress form state is compilate like italia. I put a screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0c35.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find block responsible for showing province field and add something like this right above foreach loop:

```
<option value disabled selected>{l s='-- please choose --' d='Shop.Forms.Labels'}</option>
```

Example based on "Select a country" located in prestashop\themes\classic\templates_partials\form-fields.tpl:

```
{block name='form_field_item_country'}
          <select
          class="form-control form-control-select js-country"
          name="{$field.name}"
          {if $field.required}required{/if}
          >
            <option value disabled selected>{l s='-- please choose --' d='Shop.Forms.Labels'}</option>
            {foreach from=$field.availableValues item="label" key="value"}
              <option value="{$value}" {if $value eq $field.value} selected {/if}>{$label}</option>
            {/foreach}
          </select>
        {/block}
```